# Why can't I AirDrop a folder or .zip of files to iPhone's Files app?

Tags: iphone, file-transfer, airdrop, zip, files.app

I have files on a Mac that I want to copy via **AirDrop** to the ‘**Files**’ app on my iPhone for backup purposes. They are .html, .css, .js, and similar web formats.

I do not need to modify these files on my iPhone, just archive them.

I tried doing an AirDrop transfer of the whole folder, but that didn't work. Next I tried zipping the folder, but that didn't work either. What I mean specifically by "didn't work" is that after tapping `Accept` on the iPhone, instead of being allowed to choose a save location, I am only prompted to choose an app to open the files with. Like this:

---

### AirDrop

<sup>Open with...</sup>

---

`Cancel` `QuickText`

---

Update (adding screenshots):

[image]

Then...

[image]

I don't want to try to open those files with QuickText. I simply want to save them to a folder.

What can I do instead to accomplish the archiving of the folder (or .zip) onto the iPhone?

macOS 12.6, iOS 14.8

Comment: When I AirDrop a ZIP file from a Mac to an iPhone then  I can choose “Files” to store the ZIP file in the Files app.

Comment: @MartinR Thanks for confirming. What you describe is exactly the behavior I expected and hoped for. But that's not what I'm seeing.

Comment: Pls update your question to include the exact model and operating systems of your Mac and iPhone. Have you tried this operation under the safe mode? How about using your Mac but another iPhone and also the other way?

Comment: @Alper Okay, I've added those details. Gotta run for now, sorry...

Comment: I tested it with the (current) macOS 13.5.1 and iOS 16.6. Perhaps it does not work with iOS 14, I do not have a device where I could verify that.

Comment: With iOS 16.6 I get a long list of apps which are able to handle ZIPs, including Files, and can pick the app I want. Most likely this was handled differently in iOS 14. As an alternative, a transfer via iCloud Drive should work (but may be inconvenient)

Comment: I have a similar problem except that I don't get a single prompt and the file is nowhere to be found. If I send, for example, an mp3, mp4, mkv file, then I get an error on computer side and the file cannot be sent. If I zip it, the file is sent, but nowhere to be found on the phone.